# adding and querying pointers isn't working with the REST API for Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I"m using the following commands which i've copied over from the documentation. Assume that I'm passing in the application id and keys in each curl statement for brevity.

1. create player

   curl -X POST \
   -d '{"name":"abhinav", "rank" :"amazing"}' \
   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player

Player objectId: **HgMZF6H90L**

2. Create game and add pointer relation

   curl -X POST \
     -d '{"Level" : "TWO"}' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore

GameScore objectId: **cwYIEwFaq9**

```
curl -X PUT \
  -d '{"opponents":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Player","objectId":"HgMZF6H90L"}]}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/tDiFZSE0lQ
```

Now I check from the Data browser and the GameScore object has a field with Relation. clicking on the "View Relations" navigates me to the correct list underneath. Working fine except that it says "Relation" and not pointer. Not sure if that is relevant

[image]

[image]

HOWEVER, I'm not able to query this information from the REST API. A GET results in the relation data but no objectId for the player available.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/cwYIEwFaq9
```

result:

```
{"Level":"TWO","createdAt":"2014-06-11T08:49:43.325Z","objectId":"cwYIEwFaq9","opponents":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Player"},"updatedAt":"2014-06-11T08:51:01.093Z"}
```

tried with include option but that results in some error

```
curl -X GET \
  --data-urlencode "include=opponents" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/cwYIEwFaq9
```

result:

code 107, invalid JSON

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: error means that you have bad json

Answer (score 1):

why are you using "Remove" to add a relation?  Look at the docs again.

go to Docs section "Creating Roles" again....

```
 "__op": "AddRelation",
          "objects": [
            {
              "__type": "Pointer",
              "className": "_Role",
              "objectId": "Ed1nuqPvc"
            }
          ]
```

-- EDIT
to get using "include=opponents"  you could create with this:

```
{"opponents":{"__op":"Add","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_Role","objectId":"Ed1..."}]}}
```

Comment: Sorry about that - cut and paste error. The issue still remains. I've edited the code above. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Solved :

The problem is that i needed to create an array of pointers. So instead of the "**AddRelation**", i simply need to use the "**AddUnique**" operation to create an entry for the array. So

```
curl -X POST \
 -d '{"Level" : "TWO", "opponents":{"__op":"AddUnique","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Player","objectId":"5Q4QsKF8QR"}]}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```